# The Laurent series of $\exp(1/z)$: comparing its constant term and the value at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Consider the function
   $$f(z)=e^{-1/z}$$
This function has the following Laurent series about the point  zero
      $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-n}}{n!} $$
Laurent series by definition is 
       $$ f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-c)^n
$$
     $$  a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z-c)^{n+1}}.\,  $$

For $n=0$,
   $$ a=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z-c)^{}}=f(c).\,$$

Therefore, $f(0)=1$

Is this right? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably remember the relation "$a_0=f(0)$" from Taylor series centered at $0$. But it does not apply to Laurent series.

Laurent series work differently: in general, they converge in an *annulus*, not in a disk, and therefore **do  not** represent the function at the center point. Formally plugging in $z=0$ into the series does not even make sense when it has negative powers of $z$ in it.

Comment: does that mean positive power part of laurent series isn't equal to taylor series

Comment: What Taylor series? The function $\exp(1/z)$ does not have a Taylor series centered at $0$, since it's not infinitely differentiable there (in fact it's not even continuous).